# communication between two child components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have two child components. One is a filter and another one is a table. When I click in a button which is in filter component I want to call onInit() from table component (or do something better for refresh the table). How can I do it?

something like this:

```
//function from filter component
filter() { ... }

//function from table component
populateTable(){  .... }


//I want to do something like
filter(){ this.populateTable(); }
```

Comment: Try a service for sibling communication https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 0):

> How can i do it

Organize as a heirarchy

```
- Parent
  - Filter 
  - Table
```

The *state* will be in `Parent`. A user interaction in `Filter` only requests `Parent` to change the state causing a re-render of the `Table` .

Comment: yes, my code is organized like this. Can you show me an example of... I can't make reference of table component on filter component and call that function?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution1:**

```
@ViewChild('tablecmp') tablecmp: TableComponent;
@Component({
  selector: 'filtercomp',
  .....
}
export class FilterComponent{
   filter(){
     this.tablecmp.table();
   }
}
```

**Filter Component Template:**

```
<tablecomp #tablecmp></tablecomp>
```

**Table Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tablecomp',
  .....
}
export class TableComponent{
   table(){

   }
}
```

**Solution2:**

Instead of calling the child component function (table()) from parent component (filter(). You can apply filter for the data in the parent component and send the result to child component using @input() to display.

We prefer Solution2.

Comment: thanks for your help!
But it they both are child from the same parent and a chil wants do call another child i need to use this : "<tablecomp #tablecmp></tablecomp>"


my code is like:
<div class="page-layout carded" >   
  <filtro ></filtro>  
  <table></table>  
</div>

Comment: please upvote if right. so it will be useful to others